# SSH sessions using keys extremely slow

Tags: linux, ssh

From some days I'm having trouble accessing an instance with ssh key.
This server is an Ubuntu instance where it is installed gitlab and only access via ssh key is enabled.

Checking sshd logs I see:

```
Feb 15 12:14:14 localhost sshd[16741]: Accepted publickey for git from 87.X.X.X port 54300 ssh2: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Feb 15 12:14:14 localhost sshd[16741]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user git by (uid=0)
Feb 15 12:14:14 localhost systemd-logind[1168]: New session 50 of user git.
```

but ssh connection is opened only after 2-3 minutes.

What can I check to understand why ssh connections are so slow?
Same when I do git pull using ssh, very very slow.
Instead, if I use gitlab via https, it works perfectly.

Thank you.

Comment: How about you check the SSH log files.

Comment: DNS issues are common causes for SSH delays, but rarely for more than a minute. Check if the server in question is running out of resources.

Comment: As @GeraldSchneider says, DNS is often a culprit. Check the server can resolve it's own name forwards and backwards, e.g. `host myhostname` then `host the.ip.that.comes.back`.